# Не могу подключить рекламу AdMob

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не получается подключить рекламу в андроид приложении.

Вот текст всех билдов и SDK:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

---

```
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Уже всё перепробовал но так и не смог. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ни в коем случае не выкладывайте текст скриншотами - это неиндексируется поисковиками и те, кто хочет вам помочь не смогут скопировать ваш код и внести в него правки. Вылодите всё это текстом. Плюс описшите что именно у вас не получается. В данный момент лишь видно что в одном месте вы либу подключили, во втором тоже самое, в третьем явно лишнее как и в четвёртом. Посмотрите в документации - там всё предельно ясно разжёвано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы инициализировали ее? в любом случаи загуглите как вывести тестовую рекламу, которую выводят что бы проверить работает ли, если она есть, значит все хорошо, просто сервису admob надо время, что бы начать ее показывать(и это странно, лично для меня, так как когда я писал приложку на unity реклама была сразу, а когда на студии, появилась в течении недели после публикации в маркете)